# Is there a shortcut to increment a Xaringan slide directly in the code?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, xaringan, remarkjs

I just discovered the awesome `Xaringan` package, and I'd like my presentation to be as incremental as possible.

For instance, my introduction slide looks like this:

````
```{r intro1, echo=TRUE}
version$version.string #should give 3.6.1
```

--

```{r intro2, echo=TRUE}
class(iris)
```

--

```{r intro3, echo=TRUE}
dim(iris) #row, cols
```

--

```{r intro4, echo=TRUE}
colnames(iris)
```
````

Though, I find it tedious and not much readable to write it that way.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

````
```{r , echo=TRUE}
version$version.string
class(iris)

-- 

dim(iris)
colnames(iris)
```
````

Of course, this consider `--` as code.

Is there a way to increment my slide from inside the code?

Comment: This post may give you an inspiration: https://emitanaka.rbind.io/post/knitr-knitr-code/ I know Emi will come to your post later. See if you can figure it out before she arrives :)

Comment: Thanks @YihuiXie, this is very interesting! I'm not sure I could get what I want with this way though, maybe I'm not understanding it all...

Comment: @YihuiXie Actually, this is not exactly relevent in my case. Emi's code is about showing the result of a constructed object, incremented by each line. Mine is about showing the result of each line incrementally. I'm afraid adapting her code won't make mine more readable.

Comment: Worst case is `knitr::asis_output('\n--\n')`. I guess there should be more elegant approaches, but I don't have time for this task...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yihui pretty much gave the answers in the comments but I elaborate here with one additional tweak which will ensure that the separator code (i.e. `knitr::asis_output('\n--\n')`) is not visible in the output (this is done by specifying the line number in which the separator appears in the chunk argument as below).

You can the separator code where you want to separate and just make sure the corresponding line number is not `echo`-ed.

````
---
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader: 
    seal: false
---

```{r, echo = -4}
version$version.string 
class(iris)

knitr::asis_output('\n--\n')

dim(iris) 
colnames(iris)
```
````

Comment: Awesome, Yihui indeed gave the answer but I couldn't figure out how to put it in the right place. Thanks!